# PartialFunction with recursion

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming

I have written this code sample:

```scala
val fact: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
  case 0 => 1
  case n if n > 0 => n * fact(n-1)
}
```

And it fails to compile with an error: *forward reference extends over definition of value fact*.

So my question is whether a partial function can be recursive? May be there is another syntax for that?

**EDIT**

This error seems to appear only when trying this in Scala Worksheet.

Comment: I just tested this in the repl... works fine

Comment: Yeah your code works just fine in the REPL - Scala 2.11.1

Comment: @ElectricCoffee Indeed, but in scala worksheet it doesn't. Btw. there was an answer suggesting makeing the defenition lazy, and it works, but it was deleted.

Comment: What version of scala are you using in the worksheet?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella 2.10.4

Comment: This is perfectly valid Scala code (for as far back as I can remember—definitely at least 2.9), and if it doesn't work in Worksheet that's probably a bug.

Comment: For the record, it doesn't work in scalafiddle either http://scalafiddle.net/console/6828f61cee49c7a4da0f9c1d3e03b857

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works fine in the REPL, both in version 2.10.4 and 2.11.1, so I'm afraid it's a bug in the worksheet.

I can also reproduce the problem in [scalafiddle](http://scalafiddle.net/console/6828f61cee49c7a4da0f9c1d3e03b857), but I didn't find any information about what compiler are they using.

The quick workaround for the bug is to declare `fact` as `lazy val` or `def`

```
lazy val fact: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
  case 0 => 1
  case n if n > 0 => n * fact(n-1)
}
```

or

```
def fact: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
  case 0 => 1
  case n if n > 0 => n * fact(n-1)
}
```